# How to show and hide Images on check/unchecking of a Checkbox?

Tags: javafx, checkbox, imageview, graphicscontext

I'm trying to have a few CheckBoxes visualize ingredients on a pizza in this javafx app. The Pizza is a ImageView. But I don't know how I will go about adding ingredients. Lets talk about salami for a second!

My first idea was to do this on my setOnAction of my CheckBox salami: (gc being my graphics context)

```
Image salami1 = new Image("salami.png");
gc.setFill(new ImagePattern(salami1);
gc.fillOval(250, 200, 60, 60);
```

*(I tried just adding another ImageView on top instead, but even though It was a .png which transparent background the background would still show. So I tried this instead.  Since I will only go for cheese, salami this would be fine too. This is very basic and supposed to be just for practice on my side.)*

However, How do I make the salami disappear again once I uncheck the box? I'm aware of gc.clearRect() but that's it. I'm clueless as on how to do this upon unchecking the box. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use an `ImageView` to display the image you can `myImageView.setImage(null)` and it will blank.  When you want to bring it back, simply `myImageView.setImage(salami1)`

Comment: Thats helpful, thanks. So I could just go for something like `while(cbSalabi.isSelected())`  in combination with that?

Comment: @ivanivan - Using a binding would be much less code and much simpler to implement (see my answer below).

Comment: @sontiyo - I'd check the state of the checkbox when the state changes, and set the appropriate image source at that time.  But Zephyr's answer below is even better IF all you want to do is have the same image visible/not visible tied directly to the checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply by binding the `ImageView`'s `visible` property to the `selected` property of the appropriate `CheckBox`.

Here's a quick sample:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Just creating a sample interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        CheckBox chkSalami = new CheckBox("Salami");
        ImageView imgSalami = new ImageView("salami.png");

        // Bind the salami image's "visible" property to the checkbox's "selected" property
        imgSalami.visibleProperty().bind(chkSalami.selectedProperty());

        root.getChildren().addAll(chkSalami, imgSalami);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The important part is the binding line. This is the basic logic that this line performs:

- Always set the `imgSalami` object's visibility to match whether `chkSalami` is selected.

This means you do not need to mess around with adding any loops or `ChangeListener`s to the `CheckBox`; just bind each image to the matching checkbox.

Comment: Thank you! Helped me out a lot! Im very new to properties so this was perfect